# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException:

Tags: java, android

how to solve this in android studio 4.0 in java project

i haven't used any admob in my project but then also it is showing this error. please help i tried what u mentioned in your above solutions.
but error continued....

````
2020-06-23 00:59:20.816 10332-10332/? W/ample.importcs: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2020-06-23 00:59:22.200 10332-10332/com.example.importcsv E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.importcsv, PID: 10332
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
    
    ******************************************************************************
    * The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
    * should follow the instructions here:                                       *
    * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
    * to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
    * Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
    * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
    ******************************************************************************
    
    
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6988)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6528)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6445)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
    
    ******************************************************************************
    * The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
    * should follow the instructions here:                                       *
    * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
    * to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
    * Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
    * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
    ******************************************************************************
    
    
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzyz.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.2.0:33)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.2.0:3)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6983)
            ... 10 more```
````

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the error message link and add your app id to the manifest? If so, post the relevant parts of the manifest too (change your app id though of course).

Comment: The error is automatically gone and the code is running fine.

Answer (score 1):

Only add this code to the manifest on your app and thats it

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
            android:value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In android studio go to the project structure and remove the ad dependency if you are not using it in your project.

Comment: Removing ad dependency from the app level gradle file helped me

Remove this Dependency: implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.5.0'